# Comparing Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get to compare cells between columns and spit out whether the string in range B is found in Range A. If it is found in range A it should return a match ("OK") if values of range B are not found in range A it should list out the values that are not matching.

Something like the below:

[image]

Is this possible at all with VBA?

Comment: The check is done using the values comma separated obviously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This VBA will do it for you.  Create a new module in your workbook and paste this code in ...

```
Public Function CompareCommaSeparatedValues(ByVal strSearchIn As String, ByVal strSearchFor As String, ByVal strDelimiter As String) As String
    Dim arrSearchFor() As String, i As Long, strSubSearchFor As String
    
    arrSearchFor = Split(strSearchFor, strDelimiter)
    strSearchIn = "," & strSearchIn & ","
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrSearchFor)
        strSubSearchFor = "," & arrSearchFor(i) & ","
        
        If InStr(1, strSearchIn, strSubSearchFor, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            CompareCommaSeparatedValues = CompareCommaSeparatedValues & "," & arrSearchFor(i)
        End If
    Next
    
    If Left(CompareCommaSeparatedValues, 1) = "," Then CompareCommaSeparatedValues = Mid(CompareCommaSeparatedValues, 2)
End Function
```

... now just refer to it on sheet.

I've called it `CompareCommaSeparatedValues` and provided the input for a delimiter but you can rename it as you see fit.

[image: Function]

##### Result

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

=IF(A2=B2,"OK","Not OK:")
https://trumpexcel.com/compare-two-columns/